# How to add selected Item into datagridview on button click?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a grid view and checked listbox. i wanto to add the selected items of checked listbox as a Column of the Grid View.

```
private void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listSubjects.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listSubjects.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listSubjects.GetItemChecked(i))
                    {
                        //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[i], "1");
                         DataRowView castedItem = listSubjects.Items[i] as DataRowView;
                         string item = castedItem.ToString();
                         dgvEnterMarks.Columns.Add(item, item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: do you have a lot of items in the list?

Comment: what you can do is add all in the grid as columns from start and bind their isvisible property. so if those items are selected, make the visibility property true. so only those columns will be visible

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I have done... Add the items to the collection

```
SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedSalesMultiCountries, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

bind the visibility to a property..

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn IsVisible="{Binding CompanyNameVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

now set the above property to true when the checkbox item is selected. Hope this helped. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listSubjects.Items.Count > 0)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < listSubjects.Items.Count; i++)
       {
          if (listSubjects.GetItemChecked(i))
          {
                DataRowView castedItem = listSubjects.Items[i] as DataRowView;
                string item = Convert.ToString(castedItem["SubjectName"]);
                dgvEnterMarks.Columns.Add(item, item);
          }
       }
       PopulateGridView(); 
     }
}
```